# Facebook live stream only when I'm online

Tags: facebook, livechat

I would like to show a facebook livestream box, but only when I'm online.
Is there a way to check if I'm online? 
Maybe with php?

I found some suggestions but they seem to be old....

Answer (score 1):

For your account, get an access token with the `user_online_presence` and `offline_access` permissions. Then you can run the following FQL query with that access token:

```
SELECT online_presence from user where uid=me()
```

Then just only render the livestream plugin on your page if online_presence is 'active' or maybe also 'idle'.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="fb-live-stream"
     data-event-app-id="321046074604304"
     data-width="200"
     data-height="300"
     data-xid="38b9005e85114dc9f71b6781f1d20a12"
     data-via-url="http://viadewakoplax.blogspot.com/"
     data-always-post-to-friends="true"></div>
```